# Getting error in code 'Use of unresolved identifier Firestore', but program works fine SwiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm looking for a answer, why in code I'm getting an error `Use of unresolved identifier 'Firestore'`. I imported a Firebase, program works fine, data is saved correctly, but still I get error wherever it's used

`let db = Firestore.firestore()`.

Previously, there was no such problem only when I cleaned build folder began to appear.

**EDIT**

I forgot to add that there is an entry in the Podfile `pod 'Firebase / Firestore'` and I updated the pods

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, the problem was with the `import Firebase`. Need to use `import FirebaseFirestore` instead.

Answer (score 0):

iOS projects that use Firebase no longer need the `Firebase/Core` library. Therefore, for CocoaPods users, omit `pod Firebase/Core` from the project's next pod file.

Apparently there was a bug that made it appear that `import Firebase` had been deprecated in Swift files but that is no longer the case (according to the commentor). In any event, each Firebase service can (and perhaps now should) be imported manually:

```
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseMessaging
...
```

However, to configure Firebase itself (in the App Delegate), we must (or at least certainly, can) import `FirebaseCore`:

```
import FirebaseCore
```

And it should be noted that any other buggy behavior switching these pods and imports may be fixed by cleaning the project's build folder and derived data folder.

Comment: `import Firebase` is not deprecated. There was a bug introduced in 6.28.0 that exposed an Xcode build race condition. That bug was fixed in 6.31.1.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien the bug would explain why it appeared deprecated in my projects. In what cases would we need to, or could, import Firebase?

Comment: The Firebase module is a convenience that eliminates the need to explicitly import any of the other Firebase modules.